# Issue with PyCharm Community Edition and Django runserver

Tags: python, django

I'm pretty new to coding in general and could really use someones help with this! I installed django via CMD on my WIN 10 computer and when I run the server it works.

```
D:\Python\Python37-32\website>manage.py runserver 8080
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
August 04, 2018 - 15:32:59
Django version 2.1, using settings 'website.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8080/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
```

However... I than downloaded Pycharm Community edition on my computer and instead of the server starting, I kept getting this message in the manage.py file...

```
Couldn't import Django. 
Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? 
Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
```

Im not sure whats going on here, I've been searching for an hour or so but can't seem to figure it out. Any help would e greatly appreciated, thank you in advance!

Comment: I'd also like to add, I installed the django package for pycharm and it didn't fix anything!

Comment: Did you specify project interpreter?

Comment: Hi Roman, I'm quite the noob at programming, unsure what you mean by this? Sorry about that!

Comment: Go to File -> Settings -> Project Interpreter and check that it is pointing to your python installation (D:\Python\Python37-32)

Comment: It wont let me it says, "Environment location directory is not empty".

Comment: Still not wroking i changed the interpreter and issue persists ughhhhhh

Comment: go to Files->Settings. Then, search `interpreter` in the search bar. And click on `Project Interpreter`. Add that screenshot here